# background-clip: text and backface-visibility: hidden not working as per Can I Use

Tags: css

`background-clip`: text works in Firefox (with no prefix) but not Chrome (or Safari). On researching it seems it should be the other way around (i.e. it is a proprietary webkit feature)?

`backface-visibility`: hidden works fine in Firefox and Chrome but not in Safari?

Both are shown in Can I Use as being supported in all 3?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both `background-clip` and `backface-visibility` work in **[all major browsers](https://caniuse.com/#feat=background-img-opts)**. The problem is that browsers such as Chrome **require** the `-webkit` prefix, whereas browsers such as Firefox merely **support** it.

As such, you want `-webkit-background-clip: text` in **addition** to the regular `background-clip: text`, and `-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden` in addition to `backface-visibility: hidden`. The former will work for Webkit browsers (like Chrome), and the latter will work with Firefox.

The following will work in both Chrome and Firefox:

```css
p {
  margin: 1em 0;
  padding: 1.4em;
  background: linear-gradient(60deg, red, yellow, red, yellow, red);
  font: 900 1.2em sans-serif;
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.text {
  background-clip: text;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
}

.hidden {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<p class="text">The background is clipped to the foreground text.</p>
<p class="hidden">HIDDEN</p>
```

Note that `backface-visibility` isn't supported in Internet Explorer 9 or earlier, and `background-clip: text` won't work in any version of Internet Explorer. You'd be better off using an SVG if you need Internet Explorer support.

Comment: Much appreciated for the clarification - all works fine now. As a student (web design) I would appreciate a link to a more detailed explanation of  the difference between require and (merely) support (ie that you emphasized).  In any event thanks again.